# Blender and Unity. Materials/Shaders question (Cycles, BlenderRender, Does it matter??)

Tags: unity

I have been tinkering with Unity and Blender for a fair amount of time, although mostly in Unity I don't have much 3d skills in Blender yet.

But I'm struggling to fully understand materials.

If I assign materials to areas of the mesh in Blender. (Let's say I am making a basic house. And I assign a material to each face (walls) and then a couple of windows with a separate material. Do I need to tinker with the material settings inside Blender?

I wonder this because I have been making materials in Unity for a long time, and I could easily change the materials there. But when I watch/read Blender tutorials they always make lots of changes in the material. I wonder is this because they want it to look nice in a Cycles render or whatever, or because it is needed to become a game asset.

So imagine my house in Blender is all white (like the basic Blender mesh material colour). And I just have the material1 and material2 (mat2 where the windows go), can I then import that to Unity and just set my own materials from there for transparency etc?

Anyone experienced with importing their own Blender stuff specifically for Unity use and not rendering inside Blender, please let me know your workflow for simple 3d models to Unity (with more than one material/texture)

Note: I also do use UV mapping. And it works great, but I haven't yet done one with transparent windows using UV mapping and this got me thinking that I don't need to mess with the materials/shaders in Blender.

Cheers ! :D

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Poliigon](https://www.poliigon.com/) for amazing textures if you don't want to tinker the settings manually.

In Blender, we mostly use Cycles Render engine and starting 2.80, the internal render engine(Blender Render) has been removed.

In order to tinker with the material settings, you need to make sure the render engine is set to Cycles render and select Node editor from the bottom left corner(change from 3d view to Node editor or extend a new tab and change it).

It works similar to how 3d View works, shift + a to add a new shader,x to delete, g to move etc..